# How do I add, save and load items to a listview in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listview, binding, items

About two weeks ago I started to develop in WPF and, since I only developed in WinForms, I ran into common problems but managed to find the solution for them. However, currently I'm stuck at something: adding items with multiple columns (via visual basic code, not xaml) into a listview.

I'm not sure if it's best to use a Listview or a DataGrid control for this but basically I want the user to be able to add favourite songs to a list, save them to a file and load the file whenever the app is opened. The listview currently has three columns: Artist, Song and Status.

When I was programming in WinForms, I used to do this:

```
        Dim Song As New ListViewItem
        Form1.ListView1.Items.Add(Song)
        Song.Text = TextBox1.Text
        Song.SubItems.Add(TextBox2.Text)
        Song.SubItems.Add(TextBox3.Text)
```

Then, to save:

```vb
   Dim Song As New ListViewItem
            Form1.ListView1.Items.Add(Song)
            Song.Text = TextBox1.Text
            Song.SubItems.Add(TextBox2.Text)
            Song.SubItems.Add(TextBox3.Text)
            Try
                Dim myWriter As New IO.StreamWriter(PATH_DATABASE)
                For Each myItem As ListViewItem In Form1.ListView1.Items
                    myWriter.WriteLine(myItem.Text & "|" & myItem.SubItems(1).Text & "|" & myItem.SubItems(2).Text & "|" & myItem.SubItems(3).Text
                Next
                myWriter.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Error: " & ex.Message, vbCritical, "Error")
            End Try
```

I've been searching and I've found that I need to use binding so I've tried this:

```vb
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.Windows


Public Structure Song

    Public _artist As String
    Public _title As String
    Public _status As String

    Property Artist() As String
        Get
            Return _artist
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            _artist = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Property Title() As String
        Get
            Return _title
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            _title = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Property Status() As String
        Get
            Return _status
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            _status = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Structure



Public Class WINDOW_AddSong

    Dim songs As New ObservableCollection(Of Song)




    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Song As New ListViewItem

        For Each wnd As Window In Application.Current.Windows
            If wnd.GetType Is GetType(MainWindow) Then

                DirectCast(wnd, MainWindow).Listview1.Items.Add(Alimento)
                Alimento.Content = New Song() With {._artist = "Lol", ._title = "Lol2", ._status = "Lol3"}




            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

And in the XAML listview:

```xml
<GridViewColumn Header="Artist" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Artist}"/>
<GridViewColumn Header="Title" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Title}"/>
<GridViewColumn Header="Status" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Status}"/>
```

This works however I'm not sure if this is the WPF-way of doing things.

However, I'm stuck at the saving process:

```vb
 Try
            Dim myWriter As New IO.StreamWriter(PATH_DATABASE)
            For Each wnd As Window In Application.Current.Windows
                If wnd.GetType Is GetType(MainWindow) Then
                    For Each myItem As ListViewItem In DirectCast(wnd, MainWindow).Listview1.Items
                        myWriter.WriteLine(Song, Artist, Status)
                    Next
                End If
            Next
            myWriter.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error: " & ex.Message, vbCritical, "Error")
        End Try
```

This doesn't work.
Also, PATH_DATABASE is just a directory.

To summarise, could an expert review my code and check if I'm doing things "right" and, if possible, could you help me with the saving and loading process?

Thanks.

Comment: There are many ways to save it, for example you could use a simple text file, then for each "row" of your listview you would write a line, and you would separate each "column" of it with a comma or some symbol like that. And you would load it by reading line from text file, split it at comma then putting each item in it's "column".

Comment: @CruleD Hey, in WinForms it was easy but in WPF it's much more complicated... If you could provide me a code sample or just the general idea that would be appreciated. Here's the text file saved with WinForms: https://imgur.com/a/8KatsDD Each line represents each item. Each | represents each column

Comment: I checked and code wise it looks the same as WinForms. Which part are you having issues with?

Comment: Alright so I checked some more, the idea is to create a "DataTable" and bind it to ListView as DataSource at least that's what people suggest as there are no subitems like in winforms.

Comment: Just a side note on your structure...backer fields like `Public _artist As String` should not be Public. Private is correct The data of the class can only be set by property procedures not directly from outside the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just updated your structure (I used a class, just force of habit) to use automatic property values which are available in recent versions of VS. The default implementation of properties is built in along with the backer fields. It is used just as before.

You are on the right track with ObservableCollection but you you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged by adding the Event PropertyChanged and providing the Sub OnPropertyChanged to raise the event.

Set up the bindings on the controls and set the ItemsSource ot the ListView to your ObservableList.

To save Import System.Text so you can use a StringBuilder. The loop through the list to build the string to save to a text file.

I didn't spend any time trying to make the XAML Windows look nice. Pardon the ugliness.

```
Class MainWindow
    Public Songs As New ObservableCollection(Of Song)

    Protected Sub OnLoad(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Songs.Add(New Song("Nirvana", "Smells Like Teen Spirit", "Open"))
        Songs.Add(New Song("John Lennon", "Imagine", "In Stock"))
        Songs.Add(New Song("U2", "One", "Unknown"))
        Songs.Add(New Song("Michael Jackson", "Billie Jean", "Open"))
        lvSongs.ItemsSource = Songs
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Dim frm As New frmAdd
        frm.mainForm = Me 'send the instance of the current form to the new form
        frm.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    Private Sub SaveList()
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder
        For Each item As Song In Songs
            sb.AppendLine($"{item.Artist}|{item.Title}|{item.Status}")
        Next
        'call sb.ToString and write it to a .txt file
    End Sub
End Class
```

MainWindow XAML

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_BindComboBox"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid Loaded="OnLoad"
          Name="root">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>

        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListView Margin="10" Name="lvSongs" Grid.Row="0">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="Name: " />
                        <TextBox x:Name="txtArtist" 
                                 Text="{Binding Artist, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                 FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        <TextBlock Text=", " />
                        <TextBlock Text="Age: " />
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Title}" 
                                 FontWeight="Bold" />
                        <TextBlock Text=" (" />
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Status}"  />
                        <TextBlock Text=")" />
                    </WrapPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <Button x:Name="btnAdd" Grid.Row="1" Height="25" Width="100" Content="Add a Song" Click="BtnAdd_Click"/>      
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The Song class

```
Public Class Song
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Property Artist() As String
    Public Property Title() As String
    Public Property Status() As String

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Protected Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal name As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(name))
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(art As String, Ttl As String, Stat As String)
        Artist = art
        Title = Ttl
        Status = Stat
    End Sub
End Class
```

The Add Window

```
Public Class frmAdd

    Public mainForm As MainWindow

    Private Sub BtnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        mainForm.Songs.Add(New Song(txtArtist.Text, txtTitle.Text, txtStatus.Text))
        ClearForm()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ClearForm()
        txtArtist.Clear()
        txtTitle.Clear()
        txtStatus.Clear()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Add Window XAML

```
<Window x:Class="frmAdd"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_BindComboBox"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="frmAdd" Height="172.641" Width="307.547">
    <Grid >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="Artist" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtArtist" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="16" Width="150" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="Title" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtTitle" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="16" Width="150"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Text="Status" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtStatus" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="16" Width="150"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnAdd" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Content="Add Song" Click="BtnAdd_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**EDIT**
Required Imports

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Text
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks very much for literally providing the code. :) Appreciated

I've however one question: when i add this code:
`Public mainForm As MainWindow

    Private Sub BtnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        mainForm.Songs.Add(New Song(txtArtist.Text, txtTitle.Text, txtStatus.Text))
    End Sub`
It gives me a reference error. I'm currently using direct cast because I didn't find anything that worked. In WinForms it was so much easier. Just Form1.Label1.text="aaa" for example. How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: I have tested the code and it works for me. Can you tell me what line it fails on? I guess you are referring to the dreaded NRE Null Reference Exception. When you click Add Song on the MainWindow the field mainForm is set to Me. So that shouldn't be null. I agree that things seem easier in WinForms but I think that is because I have spent years working in WinForms.

Comment: Again, sorry for the very late comment. It fails when trying to access the MainForm. It says that it's nothing: https://imgur.com/a/Ug9cggs

Comment: Also, just out of curiosity should I switch over to c# from visual basic or should I continue using vb?

Comment: Are you closing MainWindow? WPF can be confusing to WinForms programmers. In  WinForms VB does things behind the scenes to create Default instances of forms which makes it easy to access other forms. Not so in WPF. Here we have to pass an instance of the window to the second window so we can access the first window. When you click BtnAdd on the MainWindow it sets the property mainFrom on the frmAdd. Notice that we don't pass the reference to frmAdd which is just the name of the class. We pass the reference to the instance of frmAdd which is frm.

Comment: Re C# vs. vb.net.  I started with VB3 so I have been coding in vb for a long time. My brain patterning is vb. I have learned enough of C# so I can look at examples (most are in C# now) and do fairly basic coding. Both languages use the .net framework so anything you learn about the framework will work in C#. If you are young definitely learn C#. It is the cool language right now. There is a huge installed base of vb and it will need to maintained for many years to come. There are still many companies that code in vb.

Comment: Another thought; MainWindow must be your start up URI for the code to work. The reference to mainForm is set from the button on MainWindow.

Comment: Oh I get it. Since the app isn't that developed, I'll keep a backup of the wpf vb and try to move to c#. Since I already "program" in c# using Unity, it shouldn't be that different but if it is I'll switch to VB :p. By the way, I'm not closing the MainWindow and it is set as the default URI. I'll try to find what's wrong based on what you told me and until it gets fixed, should I still use directcast? Or should I avoid it? I really didn't want to 'dim AddSong as >>>New<<< Window_AddSong' nor use direct cast since it's more "unnecessary code".

Comment: In general DirectCast is good when you are very sure the cast will succeed. It skips some of the internal checking that other kinds of castings do so it is fast but dangerous. I am not quite sure where you are using DirectCast because I did not need it in my code. Creating an instance of Window_AddSong with New is absolutely necessary in WPF. This is not WinForms where vb makes the default instance available with some magic behind the scenes.

Comment: I see. I'll investigate, thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Hey, what's up?

I've been able to add the code you provided me but I have a few questions:
1. How do I change the width of each column?
2. How do I load items to the listview (now datagrid since I changed it so it looks more like excel)?

I currently have this: https://pastebin.com/3JRyn064

Comment: By the way, I fixed the part where my app would give me an exception when I tried to do "Public MainWindow As New MainWindow" and access MainWindow from the Songs Window. Apparently, I somehow completely missed the part where you said "frm.mainForm = Me 'send the instance of the current form to the new form". No more directcast, thanks so much!